# CSS transition not responding

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm new to using transitions and my transition is not responding. There must be something wrong with my code. I'm using cards on my site and I added a (mouseenter) to have the info on the card display when the mouse is hovered, it works but the transition is throwing an error there's probably something I'm not understanding, any help is appreciated!

```
        <div class="card">
            <div class="inner-card">
                <h5>Title</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sunt, libero?</p>
                <a href="">Link goes here</a>
                <div class="img-div">
                    <img src="../static/img/search.png" class="card-img" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
.card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: end;
    width: 350px;
    height: 180px;
    background: lightgreen;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.inner-card{
    display: none;
    
} 
.inner-card.active{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: end;
    background:rgba(255,165,0,0.5)
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;

}

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.card').on('mouseenter', function () {
                $(this).find(".inner-card").toggleClass('active');
            });
            $('.card').on('mouseleave', function () {
                $(this).find(".inner-card").toggleClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: "it works but the transition is throwing an error" what error do you see in the console? I put your code in a pen and it works fine: https://codepen.io/29b6/pen/xxYWdZx?editors=1111

Comment: You need to install jquery in your `<script>`. Use `<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js">`

Comment: `display`, `flex-direction` and `justify-content` are *none-animatable* CSS properties making the `transition` not work for those. Also, in the snippet after `.inner-card.active  background:rgba(255,165,0,0.5) ` there's a `;` missing causing the `transition` being skipped.
And why not use `.card:hover .inner-card {..}` instead of `.inner-card.active {..}` without the need for JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment:

- display
- flex-direction
- justify-content

are *none-animatable* CSS properties, as such `transition` and `animation` will have no effect, other *animatable* properties in the defintion are ignored.

This can be circumvented by transitioning between `opacity: 0` and `1`.

In the **snippet**, class `.inner-card` is defined as you normally would, but using `opacity: 0` to 'hide' its content.

Selector `.card:hover .inner-card {..}` is introduced to control the transition to `opacity: 1` without the need for JS.

To be complete, class `.inner-card` needs a `transition` for a smooth transition back to original when the cursor leaves the card.

```css
.card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: end;
    width: 350px;
    height: 180px;
    background: lightgreen;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.inner-card{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in-out, background-color 400ms ease-in-out;
} 
.card:hover .inner-card {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color:rgba(255,165,0,0.5);
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="inner-card">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sunt, libero?</p>
    <a href="">Link goes here</a>
    <div class="img-div">
      <img src="../static/img/search.png" class="card-img" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly for my desired effect!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and you need the text to be presented during the review, then here it is.

```css
.inner-card a{
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.inner-card{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  width: 350px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: lightgreen;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.inner-card:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  background: rgba(255,165,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="inner-card">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sunt, libero?</p>
    <a href="#">Link goes here</a>
    <div class="img-div">
      <img src="../static/img/search.png" class="card-img" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This task can be done without js. Let me know if I misunderstood you.